# How to issue a SSL certificate for a domain I do not own

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

So I'm building a multi-vendor PHP shopping cart application that runs on `*.mydomain.com`.

Now here is the problem, I host many stores on a wildcard subdomain `*.mydomain.com`. I'd like store owners to be able to forward HTTPS traffic from `shop.theirdomain.com` to `shop.mydomain.com` with their domain still visible in the browser. I can do this with HTTP by using CNAME, but HTTPS will cause a certificate mismatch because the certificate is issued for `*.mydomain.com`.

A website service I was recently using (https://www.gitbook.com/) hosts mini documentation websites. Using their platform they have a feature where you can specify your own domain `docs.mydomain.com`, from there they are able to serve their website on HTTPS and provide a certificate. All I had to do was enter a CNAME record for `hosting.gitbook.com`.

How can this be done?

Comment: They're likely using a vendor like Let's Encrypt that can use HTTP-based authentication to verify the domain.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't HTTPS's primary goal  to prevent  what you want? Or are you pulling our leg?

Comment: Just to add to @ceejayoz's comment - if you browse to [https://docs.realm.io/sync/](https://docs.realm.io/sync/), which is an example from GitBook's documentation, you'll see that the certificate is from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: It can be done by generating a cert for the subdomain after the DNS is pointed to your server. You should not be able to create a cert for a domain you don't control (and a CNAME does not imply control) - otherwise DNS would be fundamentally broken.

Comment: @davidgo A CNAME implies enough control for Let's Encrypt to issue a cert.

Comment: @ceejayoz Agreed - I worded myself badly - I was trying to say a CNAME does not imply any rights on the target of the CNAME, so if you have a CNAME of a.example.com to b.example2.com it does not give you any rights to b.example2.com.